# Context Menu - Hide all buttons and add my buttons only

Tags: vba, excel, contextmenu

I am looking for a way to hide all the buttons from the Excel context menu and just leave my buttons I created.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to do this, When i got same problem..

If you want to remove any item

```
Sub RemoveItems()
    Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls("Insert...").Delete
    Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls("Cut").Delete
    Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls("Copy").Delete
End Sub
```

Or if you want to delete all items then

```
Sub DeleteAll()
Set CtrlMenu = Application.CommandBars("Cell")
For Each Item In CtrlMenu.Controls
Item.Delete
Next
End Sub
```

If you want to restore again

```
Sub ResetMenu()
    Application.CommandBars("Cell").Reset
End Sub
```

Comment: Very Nice! That worked! It's perfect. Just one question: .Controls("Insert...") - Where do I get a list of control names?

Comment: Or you can use modify my `DeleteAll()` Function code replacing `Item.Delete` with `Msgbox Items.Caption` to know list of items